# Apache2 Ubuntu File Permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, lamp

With a fresh Ubuntu LAMP stack, I'm wondering why Apache serves up a Forbidden: Permission Denied error for my site.

Apache2 was setup with the default user/group `www-data`.

It's document root is `/var/www`

The permissions of that folder and its contents are `744 webmaster:www-data`

The webmaster is just a sudo user for maintenance and has been added to the www-data group.
But by all things, shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directory needs to have the execute permission set as well as the read permission. So

```
chmod 755 /var/www
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Correct! That seems so strange to me. Isn't that a bit counter-productive to the whole security aspect? Like php exploits for shell and file uploads.

Comment: Execute means different things for directoryes compared to files. For a directory, it means permission to enter the directory. For a file, it means permission to run the file as a program.

Comment: So safe to use it on directories but ok to exclude it on files?

Comment: In this context and with these settings, yes.